# webpack.dev.js file error unknown property 'module. Options object does not match the API schema

Tags: javascript, webpack

## Invalid options object error

### Expected behavior

Successful HTML bundle

### Actual behavior

Terminal error message - [webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. options has an unknown property 'module'. These properties are valid...

### Steps to reproduce

- npm i -g webpack, webpack-cli, webpack-dev-server
- npm i webpack, webpack-cli, webpack-dev-server, html-loader, file-loader, extract-loader
- touch src/main.js index.html
- write out some content for the html file
- touch config/webpack.dev.js
- Place the following into webpack.dev.js

```js
    const path = require('path')
      
    module.exports = {
      entry: {
        main: "./src/main.js",
      },
      mode: "development",
      output: {
        filename: "[name]-bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../dist"),
        publicPath: "/",
      },
      devServer: {
        static: "dist",
        allowedHosts: ['localhost:8080'],
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
              test: /\.css$/i,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'style-loader',
                },
                {
                  loader: 'css-loader',
                }
              ]
            },
            {
              test: /\.html$/i,
              use: [
                {
                  loader: 'file-loader',
                  options: {
                    name: '[name].html',
                  }
                },
                {
                  loader: 'extract-loader',
                },
                {
                  loader: 'html-loader',
                },
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
    };
```

### My Environment:

- Browser: Chrome
- Operating System: Windows_NT, Windows 10 Home 10.0.19044
- Node Js: 16.17.0
- NPM: 8.19.2

### Dependencies

```js
"dependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.2",
    "extract-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "html-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"
  }
```

### Additional context

The error came after I installed the html-loader, file-loader and extract-loader locally. After this I updated my webpack.dev.js file (as shown)

Scripts...

```js
"scripts": {
"start": "webpack-dev-server --config=config/webpack.dev.js",
}
```

### Possible solution

Looking through the previous posts around this I imagine its a versioning issue, but as I'm only using node js, I'd be grateful for clarification of when webpack 5 is optimal.

Comment: At first glance it just looks like you just need to move `module` up into the parent config. `devServer.module` is not valid, as the error suggests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [webpack-cli] Invalid options object. Dev Server has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema. options has an unknown property 'module'.

Move `module` up into the parent config as `devServer.module` is not valid, as the error suggests.